# looking for hadith reference on reduced blessing on sustenance for eye zina

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, zina

a scholar told it is found from hadith research that you blessings(baraqah) are lost in rizk for eye zina. where did he find that from? can anyone give me hadith number referring to this?

Answer (score 0):

There's only one Sahih hadith in which the "eye zina" term is mentioned, that is:

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying. Allah fixed the very portion of adultery which a man will indulge in. There would be no escape from it. The adultery of the eye is the lustful look and the adultery of the ears is listening to voluptuous (song or talk) and the adultery of the tongue is licentious speech and the adultery of the hand is the lustful grip (embrace) and the adultery of the feet is to walk (to the place) where he intends to commit adultery and the heart yearns and desires which he may or may not put into effect.

And it does not mention anything about Rizk.

However, there is a Daif Hadith that says: "Zina causes poverty" الزنا يورث الفقر. It was reported in Silsalat al-Hadith ad-Da'ifa by al-Albani no. 140ـ 143